# top n keys with highest values in dictionary with tuples as keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to get the top n keys of a dictionary with tuples as keys, where the first value of the tuple is a particular number (1 in the example below):

```
a = {}
a[1,2] = 3
a[1,0] =4
a[1,5] = 1
a[2,3] = 9
```

I want [1,0] and [1,2] to be returned, where the first element of the tuple/key = 1

this

```
import heapq
k = heapq.nlargest(2, a, key=a.get(1,))
```

returns [1,4] and [1,3], the highest keys/tuples with first element = 1, though if I make it

```
k = heapq.nlargest(2, a, key=a.get(2,))
```

it returns the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should take only the keys with first coordinate 1. Otherwise, there is the chance if there are a few elements with 1 as first coordinate, to get other tuples also. Then you can use `heapq` normally. For example:

```
a = {
    (1, 2): 3,
    (1, 0): 4,
    (1, 5): 1,
    (2, 3): 9
}

import heapq
print heapq.nlargest(2, (k for k in a if k[0] == 1), key=lambda k: a[k])
print heapq.nlargest(2, (k for k in a if k[0] == 2), key=lambda k: a[k])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 0), (1, 2)]
[(2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `key` parameter should be a function. But you are passing in `a.get(1,)`. What this does is calling `a.get(1,)` which is the same as `a.get(1)` which is the same as `a.get(1, None)`.

The dictionary doesn't have a `1` key so it returns `None` which means you are doing the equivalent of passing `key=None` which is the same as not passing a `key` at all: you are using the identity function as `key`.

Then `heapq.nlargest` returns the top `2` elements which are, correctly, `[1, 4]` and `[1, 3]`.

This explains why using `a.get(1,)` and `a.get(2,)` does the same thing. The above reasoning works for both values and you end up with `key=None` in both cases.

To achieve what you want use something like:

```
key=lambda x: (x[0] == 1, a[x])
```

If you find yourself using this kind of keys often you can create a key maker function:

```
def make_key(value, container):
    def key(x):
        return x[0] == value, container[x]
    return key
```

using it as:

```
nlargest(2, a, key=make_key(1, a))
nlargest(2, a, key=make_key(2, a))
```