# Python: Get top n key's with Value as dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
data = {'sachin': {'score': 15000, 'out': 100},
        'Dhoni': {'score': 8000, out: 80},
        'Shewag': {'score': 12000, 'out': 150}}
```

I want to get two players whose score are in top.

So I tried like: `key = (key for key,value in dd.items() if value['score'] > 'value').next()`

Winded here with no success.

Tried using link:[top n keys with highest values in dictionary with tuples as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006745/top-n-keys-with-highest-values-in-dictionary-with-tuples-as-keys)

As newbie to Python couldn't get around the perfect solution.

Can someone share some idea on this!!!

Output like:

```
{'sachin':{'score':15000,'out':100},'Shewag':{'score':12000,'out':150}}
```

Note: Should be top n player, just for example I need top two but It can be changed later stage.

Comment: What would the desired output of this code be?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a dictionary with "sachin" and "Shewag"'s key-value pairs? Or just the names in a list?

Comment: Question updated with more info.Please see

Comment: @M.T- You are right.Need "sachin" and "Shewag"'s key-value pairs

Comment: Quite offensive that you use `Shewag` instead of `Sehwag`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Quick Answer

Sorting works:

```
>>> dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['score'], reverse=True)[:2])
{'Shewag': {'out': 150, 'score': 12000},
 'sachin': {'out': 100, 'score': 15000}}
```

### In Steps

You sort the items:

```
>>> sorted(data.items())
[('Dhoni', {'out': 80, 'score': 8000}),
 ('Shewag', {'out': 150, 'score': 12000}),
 ('sachin', {'out': 100, 'score': 15000})]
```

This sorts by the names in alphabetical order.

Using a `key` function defined with `lambda` sorts by `score`:

```
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['score'])
[('Dhoni', {'out': 80, 'score': 8000}),
 ('Shewag', {'out': 150, 'score': 12000}),
 ('sachin', {'out': 100, 'score': 15000})]
```

Use `reverse` to get the largest one first:

```
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['score'], reverse=True)
[('sachin', {'out': 100, 'score': 15000}),
 ('Shewag', {'out': 150, 'score': 12000}),
 ('Dhoni', {'out': 80, 'score': 8000})]
```

Finally, take only the two first items with slicing and convert the list of tuples into a dictionary with `dict`:

```
>>> dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['score'], reverse=True)[:2])
{'Shewag': {'out': 150, 'score': 12000},
 'sachin': {'out': 100, 'score': 15000}}
```

Since a dictionary has no order, you only know that you have two players with top most scores. There is no notion who is first or second. If need this, you can either keep the list of tuples or convert into an `OrderedDict` to preserve the order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['score'], reverse=True)[:2])
OrderedDict([('sachin', {'out': 100, 'score': 15000}),
             ('Shewag', {'out': 150, 'score': 12000})])
```

### Do It Properly

To make it bit more reusable, you can write a function:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_top_players(data, n=2, order=False):
    """Get top n players by score. 

    Returns a dictionary or an `OrderedDict` if `order` is true.
    """ 
    top = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['score'], reverse=True)[:n]
    if order:
        return OrderedDict(top)
    return dict(top)

​
```

Now you can use it just with your data:

```
>>> get_top_players(data)
{'Shewag': {'out': 150, 'score': 12000},
 'sachin': {'out': 100, 'score': 15000}}
```

or set a different number of top players:

```
>>> get_top_players(data, n=3)
{'Dhoni': {'out': 80, 'score': 8000},
 'Shewag': {'out': 150, 'score': 12000},
 'sachin': {'out': 100, 'score': 15000}}
```

or get them in order:

```
>>> get_top_players(data, order=True)
OrderedDict([('sachin', {'out': 100, 'score': 15000}),
             ('Shewag', {'out': 150, 'score': 12000})])
```

Answer (score 4):

Your link is right. You must modify it to use it for your case.

The method is:

1. Sort descending
2. Get the n first

You can do it with the library `heapq`

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nlargest(2, data.keys(), key=lambda k: data[k]['score'])
['sachin', 'Shewag']
```

Now you can create a new `OrderedDict` to store your `dict`

```
import heapq
from collections import OderedDict
player_names = heapq.nlargest(2, data.keys(), key=lambda k: data[k]['score'])

ret = OrderedDict((x, data[x]) for x in player_names)
```

Comment: @julivico- You are correct.But I need in the form of dictionary

Comment: With the returned keys you can build a new `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1):

Good job guys, however I'm concerned how big this data will be, because if we want to take first "n" results from dictionary of many thousands of items, all of solutions there become a little cannon against a fly, we don't need to sort all of them.
I assume we want to take top N from many dictionaries of 10e4 items (and in final test 10e7 items). In such case, you might like my approach ;)

Test cases data:

```
import random
def randomized_input(n: int):
  return {str(i): random.randint(0, 10e9) for i in range(int(n))}
  
def randomized_input_rising(n: int):
  return {str(i): random.randint(1, 10e6)*i for i in range(int(n))}
  
def randomized_input_decreasing(n: int):
  return {str(i): random.randint(1, 10e6)*-i for i in range(int(n))}

test_input = [randomized_input(10e4) for _ in range(10)] +\
              [randomized_input_rising(10e4) for _ in range(10)] +\
              [randomized_input_decreasing(10e4) for _ in range(10)]
```

Tested functions: (f1-f3 written by me)

```
@timer_func
def f1(dictionary: dict, n: int=3) -> list:
  first_n = 0
  output = []
  for key, val in dictionary.items():
    if first_n < n:
      output.append((key, val))
      first_n += 1
      if first_n == n:
        output.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    elif val > output[0][1]:
      i = modified_binary_search(output, val, key=lambda x: x[1])
      output.insert(i, (key, val))
      output.pop(0)
  if len(output) < n:
    return sorted(output, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
  return output
  
def modified_binary_search(data: list, val: int, key=lambda x: x) -> int:
  """ Returns index of value in data or index right after greater value"""
  low, high = 0, len(data)-1
  match = low
  while low <= high:
    mid = low + (high - low) //2
    if key(data[mid]) < val:
      low = mid + 1
    elif key(data[mid]) > val:
      high = mid - 1
    else:
      match = mid
      break
    if abs(key(data[mid])-val) < abs(key(data[match]) - val):
      match = mid
  if key(data[match]) > val:
    return match
  else:
    return match + 1
      
@timer_func
def f2(dictionary: dict, n: int=3) -> list:
  output = []
  sorting_key = lambda x: x[1]
  iterator = iter(dictionary.items())
  for _ in range(n):
    try:
      key, val = next(iterator)
      output.append((key, val))
    except StopIteration:
      output.sort(key=sorting_key, reverse=True)
      return output
  output.sort(key=sorting_key)
  for key, val in iterator:
    if val > output[0][1]:
      i = modified_binary_search(output, val, key=sorting_key)
      output.insert(i, (key, val))
      output.pop(0)
  return output
  
@timer_func
def f3(dictionary: dict, n: int):
  ignore_less_then = float('inf')
  for idx, item in zip(range(10), dictionary.items()):
    ignore_less_then = min(ignore_less_then, item[1])
  return sorted([x for x in dictionary.items() if x[1] > ignore_less_then], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:n]
  
from collections import OrderedDict

@timer_func
def get_top_players(data, n=2, order=False):
    """Get top n players by score. 

    Returns a dictionary or an `OrderedDict` if `order` is true.
    """ 
    top = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:n]
    if order:
        return OrderedDict(top)
    return dict(top)

import heapq
@timer_func
def heap_based_solution(data, n):
  return heapq.nlargest(n, data.keys(), key=lambda k: data[k])
```

Test results:

Against all cases of randomized inputs with n=3 (top 3 elements)

```
f1                       = 0.2266796s
f2                       = 0.1764283s
f3                       = 1.0436184s
get_top_players          = 1.3699675s
get_top_playersTrueOrder = 1.3690352s
heap_based_solution      = 0.3762019s
```

Against all cases of randomized inputs with n=10

```
f1                       = 0.2584507s
f2                       = 0.2203798s
f3                       = 1.0724695s
get_top_players          = 1.4366858s
get_top_playersTrueOrder = 1.4200690s
heap_based_solution      = 0.3925653s
```

The same as above, but top 100 (n = 100). I assume this time heap will beat my approach.

```
f1                       = 0.5950816s
f2                       = 0.5384057s
f3                       = 1.0269783s
get_top_players          = 1.3860974s
get_top_playersTrueOrder = 1.3982906s
heap_based_solution      = 0.4201834s
```

And now, to specific cases. Where more or less data is in order with some errors and few displacements, n = 2 / 10 / 50 / 100 (this time, the same random data were used)

```
f1                       = 0.0830679s / 0.1377776s / 0.2902112s / 0.4260356s
f2                       = 0.0634906s / 0.1172478s / 0.2657800s / 0.4036398s
f3                       = 0.4881170s / 0.4915030s / 0.5061488s / 0.5091665s
get_top_players          = 0.4407210s / 0.4406838s / 0.4533973s / 0.4583280s
get_top_playersTrueOrder = 0.4406729s / 0.4456134s / 0.4553292s / 0.4681237s
heap_based_solution      = 0.1231322s / 0.1299584s / 0.1436498s / 0.1646721s
```

And I've dropped TrueOrder from get_top_player, this option doesn't change much in performance.

Same test as above for more or less decreasing order:

```
f1                       = 0.0615628s / 0.0605977s / 0.0615640s / 0.0669482s
f2                       = 0.0469031s / 0.0459077s / 0.0517945s / 0.0537422s
f3                       = 0.0586369s / 0.0586267s / 0.0576625s / 0.0537405s
get_top_players          = 0.4448836s / 0.4485033s / 0.4475629s / 0.4485123s
heap_based_solution      = 0.1211660s / 0.1211495s / 0.1231289s / 0.1211643s
```

Same test as two above for just random order:

```
f1                       = 0.0615599s / 0.0654719s / 0.0771964s / 0.0947835s
f2                       = 0.0498357s / 0.0527501s / 0.0654707s / 0.0845344s
f3                       = 0.4856427s / 0.4920902s / 0.5037405s / 0.5096107s
get_top_players          = 0.4778268s / 0.4876063s / 0.5023341s / 0.5223734s
heap_based_solution      = 0.1280022s / 0.1290035s / 0.1416883s / 0.1411448s
```

Conclusion:

I assume my f2 is the fastest solution there if someone needs to perform fast for a big amount of dictionary data. However, if the structure is more or less already sorted in ascending order, I believe this method could need a little more polishing to recognize this pattern and just iterate backward, that way even a heapq solution wouldn't beat that up to top 100 ;)
Another thing is extra memory space, where my solution needs just O(n) where n stands for selected top elements, and most other solutions needs extra O(N) where N stands for amount of data passed to function.

This might seems like not so much a difference now when testing, but against 3 of randomized + 3 descending and + 3 ascending data (just top 10 as I think it's the most common need, and 3 different sets for each case, because my RAM couldn't stand get_top_players solution to effectively double all data), where each dictionary has 1_000_000 (10e6) elements, it starts to scale ugly in different solutions:

```
Randomized data:
f1                       = 1.8334987s
f2                       = 1.5130723s
f3                       = 30.7836721s
get_top_players          = 30.4594269s
heap_based_solution      = 8.7966362s

Descending (with errors) data:
f1                       = 1.8028976s
f2                       = 1.3909833s
f3                       = 1.4677223s
get_top_players          = 29.4118846s
heap_based_solution      = 8.4961201s

Ascending (with errors) data:
f1                       = 2.0658695s
f2                       = 1.6451722s
f3                       = 29.5242106s
get_top_players          = 27.3624353s
heap_based_solution      = 8.4000267s
```

If someone needs the above approach of f2 for a big amount of data called often, I see two things to improve there (despite async and parallelization):

- Make iterator and a backward iterator to enhance the stability of the f2 solution.
- Consider changing the dictionary in place if that dictionary won't be needed anymore in memory, as dictionaries in python 3.8+ or 3.9+ (I don't recall) have order capabilities so far as I am concerned. It might improve this resolution a little just to move item to top n in right place (binary search on fragment [:n]) and remove element n in while loop until n element won't exist anymore.

If you need more then top 100 and more and you know data is more or less sorted with some errors in ascending order, then heapq way might be better :)

I hope it helps someone ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can easily do it by the help of `lambda` and `key` param of the `sorted` method. Refer to this [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for more clarity

```
data = {'sachin':{'score':15000,'out':100},'Dhoni':{'score':8000,'out':80},'Shewag':{'score':12000,'out':150}}

print sorted(data.keys(), key = lambda x:data[x]["score"], reverse = True)
>>> ['sachin', 'Shewag', 'Dhoni']
```

To get the top 2 results only, you may try list slicing as `lst[:2]` to get the first 2 names after sorting on the basis of score.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import getitem

data = {'sachin':{'score':15000,'out':100},'Dhoni':{'score':8000,'out':80},'Shewag':{'score':12000,'out':150}}

print(OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:getitem(x[1], "score"), reverse = True)[:2]))
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('sachin', {'score': 15000, 'out': 100}), ('Shewag', {'score': 12000, 'out': 150})])
```

If you dont need the dictionary to always be ordered, you can just do this:

```
print(dict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:getitem(x[1], "score"), reverse = True)[:2]))
```